# Finding the Inverse of a 5th order Function

Tags: inverse

I need to get the inverse of that function.  Can I get some help please?  Thanks!

$$
f(x) = -x^5-2x+2
$$

Comment: ...maybe you just have to show that it has one?

Comment: To show the existence, prove that the derivative is nonzero for all $x$.

Comment: Solutions can be expressed in terms of [the Bring radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical), which in turn can be expanded as a Taylor series or expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: Well, I know it exists, but I need to calculate a value of y out of the inverse, and plugging it in for y in the original equation doesn't seem to like me >:

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate a value of $y$ out of the inverse"? Please be specific.

Comment: Well, I need to find inverse f(4).

Comment: Do you mean $f^{-1}(4)$? Or do you mean $f^{-1}\bigl(f(4)\bigr)$? The second one is easy. The first one is a pain, and you probably need to take the approach that @hardmath suggested.

Comment: The first one.  Alright then. I guess I'll do that.  Thanks

Comment: Unless you are specifically on a course discussing the use of hypergeometric series, no sane teacher will ask you to do this in closed form. Approximate solution (Newton-Rhapson) is possible, if that's ok. Depends on the context.

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to find $f^{-1}(4)$ numerically.  This is much less than finding the inverse of function $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** :
$f^{-1}(4)=-$0.81747101900096663171875403718014803062393890731658574158584124817593022421784472707737900090539978006430155207367922222188742819732555540345960429125640051835653129488424662383631508425805621121882571...

Comment: Should I recognize this number ?

Comment: If you apply one of the methods explained in the comments, you must find this number. Otherwise, I don't think so.